# WPF Textbox Border

Tags: wpf, silverlight, textbox, border

I have a textbox that I want to validate, but when I validate it and whatever way I am setting the border seems to actually wrap the actual border I want to change inside the textbox i.e. it adds another border outside the textbox.

Has anyone got any example of how to set a pixel perfect border that doesn't look pants on an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no example for you, but here is what you can do.

In Silverlight you can override [TextBox style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061(VS.95).aspx), and play with validation controls and states in it.

In WPF you can play with [Validation.ErrorTemplate Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate.aspx). Also you can look at this article on CodeProject: [Validation in Windows Presentation Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx)

Hope I understood you properly :). But I don't know what does "look pants on an event" means [image]
.